# qnap backup without creating a network share

Tags: linux, windows, backup, network-share, qnap

Idea behind my approach is that crypto virusses attack every network drive they can find, if we can keep the backup drive 'hidden' than the virus cannot get to it.

I have a small bash script that runs on a QNAP that mounts a C:\Users folder on a given Windows PC using a specific user/passwd. After a successful mount a RSYNC runs, 'backing' up the folder, after which the folder gets unmounted. Other than a specific user (hidden) on (every) Windows PC, there is nothing needed on the Windows PCs.

Currently my script is very basic (lots of hardcoded stuff) but I want to expand it so it can reach every PC on a small biz. network, grab what is needed and disconnect.

Am I re-inventing the wheel? Is there already something like this available on QNAP (or as a Linux shell script) ?

Any other way to not 'mount' a network drive in windows but still be able to backup PCs to QNAP/NAS?

Thank you for sharing your thoughts & ideas.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I would do a different approach

- MAP the QNap from Windows, backup normally.
- From there keep a external disk plugged in the QNap, activate a scheduled dump on it daily. (the disk is not accessible outside the qnap)
- Activate the snapshot schedule too, unlike shadow copy that a crypto can corrupt, it would add another layer that the crypto might have difficulty to break.

Comment: I do use the ext. disk approach already as a 2nd layer of defense. I find the little USB disks to fail on a regular basis (even the larger WD books etc)  they are not very reliable, don't want to test those disks on a monthly basis. A 2nd QNAP is also an option but many small biz do not want to spend the $$$.

Not all biz. have access to high speed internet, so a backup-of-the-backup in the cloud is not always an option.